# Code Coverage Inline Function

Tags: android, unit-testing, code-coverage, kotlin, inline-functions

i have this function written in Kotlin

```
inline fun <T> handleEmptyResult(observable: Observable<T>,
                                 crossinline resultEmptyCheckingFunc: (obj: T?) -> Boolean): Observable<T> {
    return observable
        .flatMap {
            if (resultEmptyCheckingFunc(it)) {
                Observable.error<T>(ResultEmptyError(Throwable()))
            } else {
                Observable.just(it)
            }
        }
}
```

But when i created unit tests for this function, it shows 0 coverage on the report. I am using jacoco for code coverage. Do you guys know how to unit test inline function properly?
Thanks!

Comment: This is a Kotlin bug, currently logged here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12605

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No coverage report for inlined Kotlin methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817814/no-coverage-report-for-inlined-kotlin-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code is inlined, there are no calls to this function in your tests, and `jacoco` thinks that you never use it.

A piece of advice: forget about test coverage, it is totally useless. A project can have great tests and 30% coverage. Or someone can spend a ton of time to get 100% coverage, and still have dozens of bugs in production. I've seen both.

Comment: Ah I see, so that is the reason. Thanks for the advice @voddan

Comment: The above response doesn't answer the question btw

Comment: Still, coverage **is** good when it's unclear which code paths are used/covered and which are not, especially in legacy code.