# Inline functions are causing errors in unit test code coverage report

Tags: android, junit, kotlin

I'm writing some unit tests for my Android app written in Kotlin, and I'm getting errors from the included inlined collection functions, in this case specifically sortedBy

```
 override fun onDaysSelected(dayOfWeekList: ArrayList<DayOfWeek>) {
        view.userRoutingRule.days = dayOfWeekList.sortedBy { it.dayOfWeek }
        renderRule()
 }
```

This is the error I'm getting when I run my unit tests with coverage

> ---- IntelliJ IDEA coverage runner ----  sampling ... include patterns:
>   com.mypackage..*
>   exclude patterns:[2019.02.02 14:49:40] (Coverage): Class data was not
>   extracted:
>   com.mypackage\myfile$onDaysSelected$$inlined$sortedBy$1:
>   java.lang.Throwable
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

My unit tests all pass accordingly, but when I go to look at the coverage report, it's almost completely bare as this error stopped it from completing.

Is there any solution to this at this point? It's hard to know if I missed some condition if I can't just look at the report.

Comment: What's your `DayOfWeek` structure

Comment: sealed class DayOfWeek(
        val dayOfWeek: Int,
        val shortName: String,
        val fullName: String
) 

Note I'm also having this problem on my new file where I'm trying to sort this

ArrayList<Pair<Double, BarcodeImageAnalyzerResult>>

.sortBy { distanceAndBarcode ->
            distanceAndBarcode.first
        }

Comment: What happens if you use _Jacoco_?

Comment: Any updates for this issue yet?

Comment: Not that I've seen, but I haven't tried in Kotlin 1.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a known issue with calculating coverage of imline methods that use lambdas. (see [No coverage report for inlined Kotlin methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817814/no-coverage-report-for-inlined-kotlin-methods) and https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/inline-functions-coverage/5366)

If you want to run coverage in the current state, you'll need to use other approaches, for example implementing `Comparable` interface in your `DayOfWeek` and using `.sorted()` method.